# How to convert ruby dsl chef environment file to JSON format?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

How can I convert chef environment file which has Ruby DSL format to json?
Is that possible?

I would like to use environment file attributes in a ruby script but I cannot parse it.
Are there any way to parse these .rb files?

Thanks,

Tomszy

Comment: Chef env files are json files  - please post a sample of what you're referring to

Comment: I mean ruby DSL format. I cannot parse these files from ruby script. Json format should be easy to parse, but our env files are in ruby dsl .rb files. Like here: https://docs.chef.io/environments/#ruby-dsl

Comment: @Tomszy, Welcome to SOF!
It would be good, if the questions has the below aspects for getting better answers,
1. Objective you're trying to achieve
2. Issue or error details or code samples
3. Research effort from your end to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same way Chef does :)

https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/environment.rb

```rb
require 'chef'
Chef::Config[:environment_path] = '/path/to/directory/with/rb_file'
env = Chef::Environmment.load_from_file('environment_name') # ! => not filename!
env.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this ruby script to convert ruby DSL files to JSON.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
    
envfilename = '/path/to/environment.rb'
rolefilename = '/path/to/role.rb'

role = Chef::Role.new
role.name(File.basename(rolefilename, ".rb"))
role.from_file(rolefilename)
File.open(rolefilename.gsub(".rb", ".json"),"w") {|f| f.puts(role.to_json)}

env = Chef::Environment.new
env.name(File.basename(envfilename, ".rb"))
env.from_file(envfilename)
File.open(envfilename.gsub(".rb", ".json"),"w") {|f| f.puts(env.to_json)}
```

I got this script by modifying the code I found here: https://knife-zero.github.io/tips/use_ruby_dsl_for_envs_or_roles/